# How can I post on a user's wall on my behalf?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Let's say I am user A and there is a user B. Is there some way to use the Facebook API or anything else and post on wall of user B using programming in such a way that the post appears to be by me?

I can get any permission I want because we are close friends. I would just like to post some jokes on the user's wall automatically at regular intervals. I have gone over a few questions asked related to this topic and they suggest that it is not possible by any means. However, they are all very old and I would like to know if there have been some new developments in the API or are there any other techniques that I can use?

I have successfully posted status updates on my page using PHP but the process seems to be a bit different for posting on a user's wall. There are a lot of question like, who do I need to get permissions from? Could anyone point me in the right direction by providing link to some tutorial or the part of documentation that I need to read to get started?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I can post on my own page or on my own timeline but I have no idea how to proceed when it comes to posting on a friend's wall.

Comment: You need to get a page token I believe to post on someone else's wall.  Obviously if you're not friends then you won't be able to post.

Comment: I am a friend. :) Actually, the process is quite different from posting on a page and  Facebook's documentation is a bit hard to follow. Could you please provide links to some articles or the part of documentation that I need to read to get started?

Comment: page tokens are for pages, not for user profiles.

Comment: That is of course not possible. And even if it was it is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t post to the wall of a friend. You can only post to your own wall with the API (with the `publish_actions` permission and the `/me/feed` endpoint). This will most likely never change, as it would be considered spam in most cases.

> I would just like to post some jokes on the user's wall automatically at regular intervals.

...and that would not only be spam by definition, but also not allowed even if it would be possible. Autoposting is never allowed, and the message always must be 100% user generated.

Comment: But Tim above has commented that there is a way to do it. :)

Comment: that does not mean there is. he also commented that you need a page token, which is completely wrong too ;) - i know for a fact that it´s not possible.